# How to actually replace string while using a split in python?

Tags: python

my code looks like this:

```
text = 'some random text'
for i in text.split():
    i=i.replace('o','O')
    print(i)
print(text)
```

So basically what I'm trying to do is to modify the original text.
If i run this code my output looks like this

```
sOme
randOm
text
some random text
```

So the original text is untouched.

How I can actually modify the original text?

Answer (score 0):

For this you do not need a str split

```
text = 'some random text'
text = text.replace("o", "O")
```

After this, you can do any other operations

UPDATE BASED ON COMMENT BELOW:

```
open('file.txt','r+', encoding="utf-8") as f: 
    filedata = f.read()

words = filedata.split()

def change_word(word):
    word = word.replace("OLD_DISC", "NEW_DISC") 
    word = word.replace("'", '"') 
    word = word.replace("\\","/")
    return(word)

words = [change_word(word) if "'OLD_DISC:\\" in word else word for word in words ]
print(words)
```

NEW UPDATE:

Input Data:

```
%MACRO JUNK;
      %LET CDNC1 = A ;
      %LET CDNC2 = B ;
      %LET CDNC3 = C ;
      %LET CDNC4 = D ;
      %LET CDNC5 = E ;
      %LET CDNC6 = F ;
      %LET OFF1 = 101101;
      %LET OFF2 = 001110;
      %LET OFF3 = 011001;
      DATA JUNK (DROP =LG AIGP);
            LENGTH M1 M2 M3 M4 M5 M6 M7 M8 M9 M10 M11 M12 M13 M14 LG $2. AIGP $1. ;
            %DO H=1 %TO 6;
                  LG = "&&CDNC&H..";
                  %DO I=1 %TO 3;
                        %DO E=1 %TO 6;
    /*  if SUBSTR("&&OFF&I",&E,1) ='1' then  */   AIGP = SUBSTR("&&OFF&I",&E,1);
                              M&E = CATT(LG,AIGP);
                              M%SYSEVALF(&E+6)= CATT(LG,AIGP);
                              %IF &E LE 2 %THEN %DO;
                                    AIGP = SUBSTR("&&OFF&I",&E,1);
                                    M%SYSEVALF(&E+12)= CATT(LG,AIGP);
                              %END;
                        %END;
                  %END;
                  OUTPUT;
            %END;
            OUTPUT;
      RUN;
%MEND;
%JUNK;
```

Code:

```
with open('test.txt', 'r+', encoding="utf-8") as f: 
    filedata = f.readlines()
f.close()

def change_word(word):
    word = word.replace("CDNC", "HAHAHAH") 
    word = word.replace("%", '$') 
    #word = word.replace("\\","/")
    return(word)

filedata = [change_word(word) if "CDNC" in word else word for word in filedata ]

with open('test_finished.txt', 'w', encoding="utf-8") as f: 
    f.writelines(filedata)
f.close()
```

Output data:

```
%MACRO JUNK;
      $LET HAHAHAH1 = A ;
      $LET HAHAHAH2 = B ;
      $LET HAHAHAH3 = C ;
      $LET HAHAHAH4 = D ;
      $LET HAHAHAH5 = E ;
      $LET HAHAHAH6 = F ;
      %LET OFF1 = 101101;
      %LET OFF2 = 001110;
      %LET OFF3 = 011001;
      DATA JUNK (DROP =LG AIGP);
            LENGTH M1 M2 M3 M4 M5 M6 M7 M8 M9 M10 M11 M12 M13 M14 LG $2. AIGP $1. ;
            %DO H=1 %TO 6;
                  LG = "&&HAHAHAH&H..";
                  %DO I=1 %TO 3;
                        %DO E=1 %TO 6;
    /*  if SUBSTR("&&OFF&I",&E,1) ='1' then  */   AIGP = SUBSTR("&&OFF&I",&E,1);
                              M&E = CATT(LG,AIGP);
                              M%SYSEVALF(&E+6)= CATT(LG,AIGP);
                              %IF &E LE 2 %THEN %DO;
                                    AIGP = SUBSTR("&&OFF&I",&E,1);
                                    M%SYSEVALF(&E+12)= CATT(LG,AIGP);
                              %END;
                        %END;
                  %END;
                  OUTPUT;
            %END;
            OUTPUT;
      RUN;
%MEND;
%JUNK;
```

Comment: Even though this answer gives a solution to the problem at hand, it does not give an explanation to why the problem occurred in the first place. Can you add an appropriate explanation please?

Comment: Yup, I simplified my problem a bit in this example, i cannot process all my text (only IF some conditions are true) so the answears doesn't help me at all

Comment: can you please describe your problem so that we could have a look at it?

Comment: I need to change the path win-> linux in many script files. 
Beside the disk name i need to change slashes and quotation mark, but only in location path (for example i do no want to change " -> ' in some code because it will ruin it)

Comment: so the code looks like this with open('file.txt','r+', encoding="utf-8") as f:
    filedata = f.read()
    for word in filedata.split():
        if "'OLD_DISC:\\" in word:
            word = word.replace("OLD_DISC", "NEW_DISC")
            word = word.replace("'", '"')
            word = word.replace("\\","/")
            print(word)

Comment: try the solution I have posted as an update of the original answer. It is called list comprehension. For more info have a look at https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

Comment: Yup, I've considered this solution before, but after changing list to string all code indents from initial file are lost :(

Comment: but anyway, thanks a lot for your time mate ;)

Comment: No problem, I you provide an example of your txt file, we could still try to find a solution

Comment: let's say something like in that link https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Programming/Multiple-Do-Loop-Macro/td-p/187867 but with the libname statement (mapping the disc) f.e. libname aaa 'P:/data/My profile/work/project/';

Comment: I have posted a new update, based on the data you have send me! This is not direct solution to your problem but can be an inspiration :) I believe with minor changes, you should achieve what you are seeking :)

Comment: gr8 man, I owe you a beer :)

Comment: Upvote of the solution would be enough :)

Comment: I've upvoted it, but my rank is too low, so the upvote isn't visible :(

Comment: thanks mate! Beer sounds even better :D

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use a split you could do

```
text = ' '.join([i.replace('o', 'O') for i in text.split()])
```